# The plural form of: One's life work

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, apostrophe

I'm editing an essay about the two founders of a software company, and there is a sentence that currently reads:

> They have made it their **live's** work..."

This looks and feels wrong, but I'm having a brain fart and need some help. Should it be:

- Their life's work
- Their live's work
- Their lives work
- Their lifes work

What's the correct way to write this?

---

Please reconsider opening this question, which was closed for being off topic. The "specific source of concern in the text" has indeed been identified, it's been highlighted clearly and several alternatives have been offered by the OP. And as FumbleFingers commented:

> *...it seems pretty obvious from the comments here that we're not dealing with a trivial issue that could have a single obvious answer*.

Comment: *live* is the verb, *life* is the noun, so *live's* is not even grammatical. It should be *their life's work*.

Comment: What about *lives'*?

Comment: @IanMacDonald - No. [One's] **life's work** is such a well-established expression that any deviation from it sounds wrong (in my view, anyway).

Comment: In this case, it is not *one*. It is *two*.

Comment: @IanMacDonald - That doesn't matter. It would still sound wrong to me. But if you feel strongly enough, it's your call.

Comment: @ErikKowal I didn't realise this was a site for opinions.

Comment: I think **life's work** is effectively a single unit. You can tack a pluralising **s** on it, but you can't tinker with the internal structure. This usage looks good to me: [*To what extent were **their life's works** rooted in the "edifice which had lost its foundations"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22+extent+were+their+life%27s+works%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: ...but I really do think an anonymous closevote for *proofreading* is a bit OTT! I think loads of things, @Ian. So does everyone else here. :)

Comment: @IanMacDonald - The answer window is for answers; the comments are for comments, including opinions. That's what makes them different from answers.

Comment: That sentence is nearly correct, except that -- "**their lives'** work ..." -- the apostrophe goes **after** the *s*.

Comment: @MartinKrzywinski Is that some kind of English? And who all up voted that comment !! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers No idiomatics at the expense of semantics. It is the **combined work of two lives** that's all.

Comment: @Kris: Google Books claims 287 instances of [whose lives' works](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22whose+lives%27+works%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (it doesn't index punctuation marks), but I can't see *any* that match this context - they're all accidental collocations. Although there are only 27 [whose life's works](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22whose+life%27s+works%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), most of them *do* seem to match. For example, *generations of paleontologists and morphologists whose **life's works** were devoted to these problems.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers All are correct and make sense, their suitability depending on what one intends to say. It's not about grammar, it's about the intent of the statement.

Comment: Why is this question being close-voted? It's not about proofreading, the OP knows something is wrong and has offered several alternatives. @Kris the second can't be correct. How would you interpret it?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I don't even understand why it's been getting *downvotes*. I haven't perused your answer yet, but it seems pretty obvious from the comments here that we're not dealing with a trivial issue that could have a single obvious answer. But although it therefore *is* to some extent a matter of opinion, I'd be interested to see *why* people endorse or reject any particular "solutions".

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a universal consensus on this point. I would suggest that the OP chooses the form he or she prefers and remain faithful to that.

> [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/life-s-work?q=life%27s%20work) **life's work** *noun* [U]  (US lifework)
>
> Your life's work is the work that is most important to
>   you and to which you give a lot of time and effort: *Her garden was her life's work*

1. Without the possessive apostrophe (an unusual construction)

   - Now, at mid-life, at an average age of 44, the subjects can be considered to be pretty well established in **their life work** <sub>[source](https://books.google.it/books?id=7IWaAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA73&dq=%22their+life+work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DeYEVabkM8j5ywOxh4L4CA&ved=0CFQQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22their%20life%20work%22&f=false)</sub>
   - At this point, many individuals become concerned about their generativity, **their life work**, and connecting to social or spiritual realms outside of the self <sub>[source](https://books.google.it/books?id=303V2P3cvUwC&pg=RA1-PT264&dq=%22their%20life%20work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DeYEVabkM8j5ywOxh4L4CA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22their%20life%20work%22&f=false)</sub>
2. The singular noun with the possessive apostrophe i.e. *life's*

   - After concerns about money, the next major obstacle that holds people back from taking up the quest for **their life's work** is fear of breaking away from the pack. <sub>[source](https://books.google.it/books?id=7qexzycOfKcC&pg=PT35&dq=%22their%20life%20work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zzkEVa62LcnXyQP58oDABQ&ved=0CCYQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=%22their%20life%20work%22&f=false)</sub>
   - Reflecting upon **their life's work**, Thuli and Catharine envisaged a multigenerational timeline in which their children and grandchildren would benefit from their hard work. <sub>[source](https://books.google.it/books?id=4uYrqTwMZB4C&pg=PA180&dq=%22their%20life%20work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GUoEVfqmAcbqyQP4tYLoAQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBjge#v=onepage&q=%22their%20life%20work%22&f=false)</sub>
3. The plural noun with the apostrophe after the suffix -s; i.e. *lives'*

   - They imagined it as a time for reflection and recollection of **their lives' work** and their relationship together. <sub>[source](https://books.google.it/books?id=jG6Og2DRqWUC&pg=PR9&dq=%22their%20lives%27%20work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gjkEVYKWCILSygPeiYDYBA&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCTge#v=onepage&q=%22their%20lives'%20work%22&f=false)</sub>
   - Women listed their children as a validation of **their lives' work** <sub>[source](https://books.google.it/books?id=VeF6NVpRII4C&pg=PA42&dq=%22their%20lives%27%20work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gjkEVYKWCILSygPeiYDYBA&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBjge#v=onepage&q=%22their%20lives'%20work%22&f=false)</sub>

---

It can also be written as one word

> **lifework** noun
>   1. the complete or principal work, labor, or task of a lifetime.
>   1870-75; *life* + *work*
>
> - *The introducer explained that my research had disproved part of my adviser's lifework, and the shock had killed him*
> - *It is also being used with adults who want to clarify [**their lifework**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lifework) objectives and perhaps make mid-life career changes.*

4. As an 'uncountable' noun i.e. *lifework*

   - *how these individuals, with different backgrounds and located in different situations, go about organizing **their "lifework"** and how this ties into their access to social services...* <sub>[source](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZQlvAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA176&dq=%22their%20lifework%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YkAEVZ_NHIqAzAOKyYLoAg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22their%20lifework%22&f=false)</sub>
   - *... what we want is teachers who have made teaching **their lifework**, [...] and the number of those who make teaching **their lifework** will soon be greater than those who consider it simply a business* [source](https://books.google.it/books?id=MkpBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA43&dq=%22their%20lifework%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YkAEVZ_NHIqAzAOKyYLoAg&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22their%20lifework%22&f=false)

---

**N.B** The expression *their lives work* is a little unusual but nevertheless grammatical. In this instance, *work* is used as a verb meaning to produce a desired effect or result; to succeed. E.g. *[my deepest satisfaction in work is to give people insights that help **their lives work** better](https://books.google.it/books?id=zJwJ-0q52QsC&pg=PA52&dq=%22their%20lives%20work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=o1IEVfyyGquqygOJ8YKwBQ&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22their%20lives%20work%22&f=false)*

Comment: Searching Google Books for [***their** lives' work **but***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22their+lives%27+work+but%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) screens out most of the "false positives". But it only claims about 308 hits, compared to about 10,100 for [*their **life's** work but*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22their+life%27s+work+but%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (where virtually *none* are unwanted accidental collocations).

Comment: @FumbleFingers there are many examples for [*their lifework*](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22their+lifework%22&oq=%22their+lifework%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.11713j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22their+lifework%22&start=0) which yields 10,200 results. Admittedly  in Google Books: [**their lives' work**](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22their+lifework%22&oq=%22their+lifework%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.11713j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22their+lives%27+work%22&tbm=bks&start=80) I had to sift through the results, but I believe there are many more than 308 instances.

Comment: It doesn't help that neither Google Books nor Google *Internet* searches take any notice of apostrophes, but [my Internet search](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22their+lives+work+but%22) returns "About 190,000 results". But when I actually scroll through them it peters out at page 4 with only 35 hits (most of which are irrelevant matches like *[people try] to make their lives work, but [they fail]*, I don't say the noun ***lifework*** (whether one word, hypenated, or two words) is "invalid". Just that the *standard* singular version is ***life's work*** (two words, with an apostrophe).

Answer (score 1):

Of OP's four suggestions, only the first...

> *Their life's work*

...is remotely credible, on the grounds of basic grammar.

The second fails because *live* isn't a noun. Only nouns can take the [Saxon genitive](http://www.odlt.org/ballast/saxon_genitive.html) **'s**.

The remaining two fail because they don't include any possessive marker at all. It's an integral part of the "base form" that isn't *dependent* on "plurality", so I see no justification for discarding it. Besides which, *lifes* in #4 isn't a valid plural except in special cases such as [*several **still lifes***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22several%20still%20lifes%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_life)).

In OP's specific context it's reasonable for *work* to be in the singular, because it applies to a single *collaborative* effort (the software company). But even where the reference is to *multiple, independent* efforts, people usually don't pluralise to *works*...

> *But seven artists stood out: Braque, Chardon, Duchamp, Hals, Peale, Sloan, and Trumbull produced 8% of [their life's work](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-dNcKDWnaCgC&pg=PA112&dq=%22of%20their%20life%27s%20work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ii0EVa3cDOfW7Aa_n4GQDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20their%20life%27s%20work%22&f=false) in the 80s.*
>
> *...dozens of scientists, spiritual leaders, and social activists make the telling of a sacred evolutionary story part of [their life's work](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=odRMKOrr6FYC&pg=PA105&dq=%22of%20their%20life%27s%20work%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AjkEVZb8HfON7AaM2IDwBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20their%20life%27s%20work%22&f=false).*

Having said that, I think pluralising is sometimes a perfectly justifiable choice...

> *[We] picked cartoonists [whose life's works](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aWrqAAAAMAAJ&q=%22whose%20life%27s%20works%22&dq=%22whose%20life%27s%20works%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9SkEVfD7JtGO7Qbp0IG4Dw&redir_esc=y) would be most familiar to the average citizen.*

---

TL;DR: the collocation ***life's work*** is effectively an established *single syntactic unit*. You can modify the entire thing by adding a pluralising **s** (although in fact most people *don't*, even where semantically justified), but you can't tinker with the internal structure, so ***life's*** must remain unchanged.

Which is semantically sensible anyway, since each individual ***life*** is normally only dedicated to a single ***work***, even if you're actually talking about the "works" of multiple "lives".

Answer (score 0):

I can see that what you are trying to do is use the plural and yet also apply the possessive.  When a word ending with "s" is possessive, just add an apostrophe to the end of the word.

Here is a quote from http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/apostrophes/apostrophes-with-words-ending-in-s/

> Rule 2: To show plural possession of a word ending in an s or s sound, form the plural first; then immediately use the apostrophe.
>   Examples:
>   the classes’ hours,
>   the Joneses’ car,
>   guys’ night out,
>   two actresses’ roles...

So the spelling you're looking for is:

> "They have made it **their lives' work...**"

Answer (score -1):

What about "their life-work"? I don't know whether this word composition exists or is usual in English, but it is usual in German (Lebenswerk).

Amendment

Though my COD has only life's work the BNC gives 9 examples for life work (without hyphen). One example is:

- It was at his home that Galileo renewed his life work, that on mechanics and motion.

http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=life+work&mysubmit=Go

Plural: Probably "they + their life work".