# Can you use a plural of Life as Life's when using as "Life's Boat" or "Life's Boat's"

Tags: nouns

Hi I am trying to understand the if it is ever possible to use Life's. I know technically the plural for the word life is Lives but I am still curious.

Sorry maybe I am not to clear on it. I would use the term Life's Boats not in the typical manner of a Life Boat. But in the descriptive manner for a boat that fits every aspect of life.

Comment: A [noun adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), or attributive noun (that is, a noun performing the role of an adjective to modify another noun), is never pluralized.

Comment: "Life's" is the possessive form of "life", or a contraction for "life is".

Comment: @Mike, Can you elaborate on what you mean by "a boat that fits every aspect of life"? What does that mean? What kind of boat is it?  What are its attributes?  Why do you want to pluralize "life" to achieve this effect?

Comment: Dan I don't want to get to much into it. But here is another look at it. Is this sentence grammatically correct? Is the possessive form of the singular noun life, life's. 

 example: These volumes represent his life's work.

Comment: @Mike, you can say "*His life's work*", but there *life* isn't plural. It's singular, and it's attributing the possession of the work to his life. It is the work **of** his life. By contrast, you cannot ascribe the possession of the *boat* to his life; that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Related: [The plural form of "one's life work"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233538/the-plural-form-of-ones-life-work)

Answer (score 1):

In the phrase "life boat", life in a nominal adjective: a noun acting as a description of the type of boat.  In that case, "life" will never be plural.

> Two of the life boats sank.
>   Life alert systems are important in home health care.

The plural of life (lives) will certainly be used in many instances, but always as a noun and not an adjective.

> Many lives were saved by other emergency boats.
>   Alert systems are important for the lives of elderly in home care.

If however you wish to use the possessive of life, something that belongs to life, then use the apostrophe and *s* as with most possessives.  In this way, possessives do not change the structure of the noun involved.

> It can be hard to keep up with life's chaotic changes.
>   All of life relies on each other as though we were the crew of a huge boat called Earth.  Let's not capsize life's boat.

If you wish to check if something is a possessive, try to reword it with the word "of":

> the chaotic changes of life
>   the boat of life

Comment: Sorry maybe I am not to clear on it. I would use the term Life's Boats not in the typical manner of a Life Boat. But in the descriptive manner for a boat that fits every aspect of life.

Comment: That is in fact not a plural, but rather a possessive.  The boat which accompanies all life is "life's boat".  I will add a section concerning that to my answer.

Comment: 'life [is] a nominal adjective: a noun acting as a description of the type of boat.' [True] ... 'In that case, "life" will never be plural.' Very probably true, but have you evidence to support this claim?

Comment: I can't present proof (frankly I have no idea if someone has chronicled this), but I can show constructions where the plural is expressly *removed* when something turns into a nominal adjective: i.e. *a five day drive* or a *two-hour seminar*.