# Which is correct? "my life work" or "my life's work"

Tags: grammaticality

Which is correct? to say "my life work has consisted of..." OR "my life's work has consisted of..."

Comment: Related: [The plural form of: One's life work](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233538/the-plural-form-of-ones-life-work) but the question is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Work is possessive to "life". You can reformulate as to say "The work of my life consisted of...".

Therefore you end up with the second option: "My life's work has consisted of..."